# how to call fragment from Navigation drawer?

Tags: android, fragment, navigation-drawer, android-recyclerview

please help me i am new to android.
I can display toast by clicking item in navigation drawer but how can i open new fragment from navigation drawer.

My code in NavigationDrawerFragment is

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        adapter = new EduAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "On click  " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "On Long click  " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "On long click  " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }));
        return layout;
    }
```

and in main activity is :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_appbar);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment =
                (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

please help me to open new fragment from drawer as i can only display toast.
i wqas following Slidenerd Material design Video .

Answer (score 0):

Create a class which extends Fragment Activity and then you can open the new fragment as shown below from the new class:

```
    DetailViewFragment f1 = new DetailViewFragment(); 
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_layout, f1).commit();
```

In your onItemClicked method Navigate to the class created.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: where should i create class
in main activity??
ani then can i use switch case?

Comment: No create a new activity and extend Fragment Activity and then for setContentView () set the layout of fragment and use it as I have shown. In your navigation drawer fragment onItemClicked() method you should use switch.

Answer (score 0):

On Your RecyclerView's item click you simply have to add the corresponding fragment this way.

```
 getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(your_container_id,
                            new YourFragment(), YOUR_FRAGMENT_STRING_TAG)
                    .commit();
```

Please keep in mind that for each position click of the recyclerview you will add your fragment in the above way. You can probably use switch cases inside your onItemClick of the recyclerView.
See if it helps you!!! Tell me if you need any other help!!

Comment: Do i have to create new class in main activity and then use switch case??

Comment: No you need to implement this in your onItemClick method

Answer (score 0):

Create a method and pass the item position in Recylerview's onitemclicklistener

```
public void changeFragment(int position) {
 switch (position) {
   case 0:{                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, calenderFragment).setTransition                (FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                break;
            }
            case 1:{                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new PatientProfileFragment()).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                break;
            }     
        }
    }
```